# Jquery Validate not working, only email validation working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate to validate a form on my website.

For some reason the email validates works. however, equalTo and my custom requirement do not work.

Have I missed a trick?

```
 <form id="form1">
             <input class="input1991 savage" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" ><br>
             <input class="input1991 savage" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email"><br>
             <input id="password" class="input1991 savage" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"><br>
             <input class="input1991 savage" name="password2" placeholder="Password Verification" type="password"><br>
</form>

$(function(){
        $.validator.addMethod('minChar', function(value, element) {
            return this.option(element)
            value.length >= 6;
        }, 'Please enter more then 6 characters')

        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                },
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minChar: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minChar: true
                },
                password2: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#password",
                    minChar: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: 'Please enter test',
                    email: 'test22'
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validation method seems to be faulty.

Just use:

```
return value.length >= 6;
```

Which returns true or false. There is no need to use element in there.

```
$.validator.addMethod('minChar', minChar, 'Please enter more than 6 characters');

function minChar(value, element) {
    return value.length >= 6;
}

$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minChar: true
        }
    }
});
```

Test cases:

```
Name = jack;   // false
Name = johnny; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your custom rule that is breaking the built-in `equalTo` rule. Also, jquery.validate has a rule similar to your `minChar` already implemented.

```
$('#form1').validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
    }
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be a bad idea to check your JavaScript console for errors.

Your code...

```
$.validator.addMethod('minChar', function(value, element) {
    return this.option(element)
    value.length >= 6;
}, 'Please enter more then 6 characters')
```

It's not `this.option(element)`... it's `this.optional(element)`

You also forgot the "or" operator.  I added the extra parenthesis for clarification...

```
return ( this.optional(element) || (value.length >= 6) );
```

complete...

```
$.validator.addMethod('minChar', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.length >= 6;
}, 'Please enter more than 6 characters')
```

---

That being said, **you do not need to create a custom rule for this**.

[Just use the `minlength` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/).

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        ....
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        ....
```